# Keep Scroll position when elements above toggle visible/invisible

Tags: javascript, css

searching for this did not find a proper answer, yet I am sure I am not the only one having this issue.

I do have a loooong page (up to more than 10000px height) with lots of 's. Some of them are set to display:hidden and zero height using this css class:

```
.invisible {
    visibility:hidden;
    height:0px;
    margin:0 !important;
    padding:0 !important;
    border-width:0 !important;
    min-height:0 !important;
}
```

So my html basically looks like this (I omitted the closing tags):

```
<div class="invisible">
<div class="invisible">
<div class="invisible">
<div class="invisible">
<div class="invisible">
<div class="invisible">
<div>
<div class="invisible">
<div>
<div>
<div>
<div>
<div class="invisible">
<div class="invisible">
<div class="invisible">
<div>
<div>
<div>
<div>
```

So if I am in the middle of the page and toggle all .invisible classes, the page gets a lot higher (because all the divs that were .invisible regain their real height), and the element(s) that were on screen before are not any more.

And that is exactly what I want to achieve: Keep the element that was on-screen before toggling on-screen after toggling, so the user does not really notice any scrolling.

I can think of a way doing this:
1) Somehow find out which element is on screen and how far it is from the screen top (thats where I fail at this idea)
2) when toggling, scoll until exactly this state is reached again

As my JS aint too good, there maybe a better way than my initial idea...

Best regards
Philipp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it using [document.elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint), below there's a working demo but it doesn't seem to be working 100% inside SO's sandbox so please also check https://jsbin.com/hozazusone/1 (it might need some fine-tuning):

```js
$('#toggle').on('click', function(){
  var top = $(document.elementFromPoint(window.innerWidth/2, 10))
  var howMuchFromTop = top.offset().top - window.scrollY
  $('.invisible').removeClass('invisible').addClass('red')
  window.scrollTo(0, top.offset().top - howMuchFromTop)
})
```

```css
.invisible {
    visibility:hidden;
    height:0px;
    margin:0 !important;
    padding:0 !important;
    border-width:0 !important;
    min-height:0 !important;
}

div {
  background: #cccaaa;
  height: 110px;
  margin: 4px 0 0 0;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}


#toggle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div class="invisible">3</div>
<div class="invisible">4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div class="invisible">6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div class="invisible">8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
<div class="invisible">13</div>
<div class="invisible">14</div>
<div class="invisible">15</div>
<div>16</div>
<div>17</div>
<div>18</div>
<div>19</div>
  <div>20</div>
  <div>21</div>
  <div>22</div>
  
  
  <button id="toggle">toggle</button>
```

Comment: Wow, this is super-awesome, thanks a lot! 
elementFromPoint() was what I was missing, goot to know that one.

Comment: Glad it works for you. As for browser support it seems to be fine https://caniuse.com/#feat=element-from-point